# JS sup() displaying tags in html

Tags: javascript, html

Im a using .sup() function in Javascript to convert a text to superscript. However, when I load the webpage ; it shows the text along with the  tags and no sign of a superscript.

```
outputtext[2] = "O(n"+"3".sup()+")";
```

This is what gets displayed on the webpage .

```
O(n<sup>3</sup>)
```

I want 3 to be displayed as a superscript. How can it be solved ?

EDIT:
This is how I am printing contents of outputarray .

```
inner.textContent = outputtext[(Math.log(tile.value) / Math.LN2)] || '';
```

I call textContent separately later .

Comment: Are you using jQuery or plain old javascript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that you are inserting `outputtext[2]` into the page via the `.textContent` property of an element. This will insert the string *as is* into the element without parsing & rendering it as HTML.

For situations like this, there is an `innerHTML` property. Once this property is modified, it's value is rendered as HTML and any tags found within the value will be displayed as expected.

```
element.textContent = outputtext[2];  // bad
element.innerHTML = outputtext[2];    // good, will display 3 as superscript
```

---

If you're using jQuery, use `.html()` instead of `.text()`

```
$(ele).html(outputtext[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The output text is getting HTML Encoded.

You need to display the raw string instead.

You need to show how:

```
outputtext[2]
```

works for any further help.

Comment: I didnt quite get you !

Comment: how does the "outputtext" array display data on the webpage? You need to paste more of your code, or else no one can help you.

Comment: Don't use .textContent, use .innerHTML